# Конструкция if не сравнивает введённый текст пользователем

Tags: python, if, условия

при вводе в консоль ответа с маленькой буквы - условия не работают и Питон перескакивает на else, не засчитывая мой ответ.
Однако стоит мне ввести тот же ответ, только с заглавной буквы, то программа работает как надо.

Почему такая ситуация происходит? Разве `if answer == ('Да' or 'да'):` не говорит Питону: если Да или да, то выполни следующее? Разве он не должен работать в обоих случаях?

Скрин работы программы прилагаю.
[image: f]

```
while True:
answer = input('Вы Василий? ')

if answer == ('Да' or 'да'):
    print('Хорошая вода!')

elif answer == ('Нет' or 'нет'):
    print('Сделай мне омлет.')

else:
    print('Я вас не звал, идите лесом.')
```

Comment: Работают ленивые вычисления для `or`. `('Да' or 'да')` всегда будет `Да`, `('Нет' or 'нет')`  всегда будет `Нет`. Т.е непустое слово уже истина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ уже дали, а я объясню, почему ваш вариант не правильный.

При вычислении логического выражения

```
answer == ('Да' or 'да')
```

сначала вычисляется выражение `or` в скобках, а затем производится сравнение `==`.

```
>>> answer = "да"
>>> ('Да' or 'да')
'Да'
>>> answer == ('Да' or 'да')
False
```

А вам нужно сначала сделать сравнение `answer` два раза,
а потом лишь проверять, было ли одно из этих сравнений `True`:

```
>>> answer == 'Да'
False
>>> answer == 'да'
True
>>> answer == 'Да' or answer == 'да'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if answer == ('Да' or 'да'):
> ```

```
if answer == 'Да' or answer == 'да':
```

```
if answer in ['Да', 'да']:
```

```
if answer.lower() == 'да':
```